RabbitMq Queue Getting TCP connection lost
Trying to upload media of above 11MB, But Queue connection is getting lost, But other Queues are working fine, Queue which got connection lost, Getting messages in Ready State without acknowledge.
(https://i.sstatic.net/6ZpQ6WBM.png)
Again I have to restart consumer to get the connection back to this queue.
When I Get Message, I got truncated payload(https://i.sstatic.net/1Kyjrsh3.png)
Any help would be appriciated.

There is a similar topic Here
Additionally, I recommend using Json format to encode your objects instead of "x-java-serialized-object"
Example of converters https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yuApTF_HeWM&t=681s for use JSON

Thanks for you're time, I guess the problem is because my consumer is running in linux OS, RabbitMq in Windows, I upgraded amqp and spring-rabbit jar's, It worked for me. Other than OS I didn't find any other issue.
